# positive real numbers satisfying $\frac{(a+b)^3}{a^2b}\geq\frac{27}{4}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive real numbers. Prove that
$$\frac{(a+b)^3}{a^2b}\geq \frac{27}{4}$$

I tried to use looking backward strategy
$4(a+b)^3\geq27a^2b$

but i got troubled in simplifying further result. Any other effective idea?

Comment: .....AM-GM.....

Comment: I would start by finding where the minimum would occur. Partial derivatives, perhaps ...

Comment: There is no $c$ in the inequality ? !

Comment: Nice idea, let me try. . Thanks

Comment: No, there is no $c$ in the inequality

Comment: But you wrote: "Let a,b and c be positive real numbers. "

Comment: Ooh i am sorry, that was my bad

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $AM \ge GM$ for $a/2,a/2,b$
$$\implies \frac{a/2+a/2+b}{3} \ge (\frac{a}{2} \frac{a}{2} b)^{1/3}$$
$$\implies \left(\frac{a+b}{3}\right)^3\ge \frac{a^2b}{4}\implies \frac{(a+b)^3}{a^2b}\ge \frac{27}{4}. $$
the equality holds when $a=2b$.

Comment: Wow, thats amazing. . Thanks for the help  i am so weak in inequality

Comment: @Abu Nussa Welcome, now you are supposed to accept an answer.,

Comment: @ZAhmed: First the poster is supposed to ask a good question (provide context, show attempts, ...). Ideally a  bad question should not be answered before it is improved :) Often that encourages more bad questions, and lowers the quality of this site.

Answer (score 0):

The formula is homogeneous, so with $t:=\dfrac ba$,

$$\frac{(t+1)^3}{t}\ge\frac{27}4.$$

You can compute the minimum by differentiating.

> The numerator of the derivative is $2t^3+3t^2-1=(t+1)^2(2t-1)$. The positive root  yields the value of the minimum, $\dfrac{27}4$.